# Chromecast icon disappear on android device

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

We use the API of‘google play service’ and ‘android-support-v7-mediarouter’API to search the Chromecast，at first, we can find the Chromecast, then we do nothing, but the API return ‘remove’ after a while, and the Chromecast icon disappear, we need to search it again.

device：Nexus 7 ， Android 4.4.4 
google play service lib version：5.0.77-000

test code：https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

Comment: There is a known discovery issue in the latest Google Play Services update. We are working on a fix.

Comment: You can subscribe to this issue tracker item to be notified when it is resolved: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=314